# EXTJS 6 app in .war deployed on jetty, behind proxy

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have EXTJS 6 app packed in web app (.war) deployed on jetty server behind apache proxy

Proxy is configured to proxy requests to my jetty node server

example:
https://my.domain/sencha << internet addess
is proxied to internal jetty server
http://jetty-node-1/my-sencha-webbapp << node address

Problem:
I don't know where to set /sencha uri in my extjs app as base path so that everything is loaded  relatively from /sencha path instead of / path

Regards

Armando

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it.

In `app.json` I added this setting

```
"base": "${app.dir}/sencha/"
```

Now it knows all about the relative path.

Snippet from `app.json`:

```
"production": {
    "output": {
        "appCache": {
            "enable": true,
            "path": "cache.appcache"
        },
        "base": "${app.dir}/sencha/"    
   },     
}
```

please note that this creates sub folder `${app.dir}/sencha` in which your production build will be.

Regards
Armando